# How to programatically add files to an existing tar file

Tags: unix, language-agnostic, tar

I have one process that creates a tar based on some existing files, then I want another process to take that tar file and add MORE files to it.

How is this accomplished programmatically?

Comment: `tar -r` appends to the tarfile. What more do you want?

Comment: Can it place a file at a specific location in the tar file?  (Assuming there is some kind of folder structure)

Comment: Location? You mean you want the new file `foo` to go in as `/some/path/foo`, or you want it to be the third file in the tarfile, or you want it to begin 140kB from the beginning of the tarfile?

Comment: Within the tar file, there is a folder /some/path, and I want to add a folder /foo/bar rooted at /some/path

Answer (score 3):

There are no folders as such in a tarfile. Each file can have a path, so a tarfile might contain

```
/some/path/foo
/some/path/bar
/another/path/baz
```

If you have a file `/elsewhere/quartz` which you wish to add to the tarfile as `/some/path/quartz`, this will do it:

```
tar -rvf tarfilename --transform 's,.*/,/some/path/,' /elsewhere/quartz
```

(This will work in GNU tar, I can't make promises about other versions.)

The stuff inside the single quotes is a regular expression substitution command, roughly "take everything up to a slash (as much as possible) and replace it with `/some/path/`".

Comment: Wait, what? I just tried `tar -rf files.tar file2` on a tar called files.tar, that had a file called file1 in it, and when I deleted the files and untarred files.tar (`tar -xf files.tar`), I got both files back. It also worked with directories just fine. I don't see the necessity for that over complex solution.